# MeteorJS: Twitter _oauth blank and doesnt login

Tags: meteor, twitter, package, authorization

I am having issues after adding the `accounts-twitter` package.

When I try to login with Twitter, the "Twitter/authorize" box is blank.

When I inspect in the console I see the error:

`Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin(ip address).`

In my dev.twitter settings the web address and callback is set to the appropriate domain name.

Has anyone run into a similar issue?

I am using Digital Ocean to host the app. This is only happening on Digital Ocean and works fine on my local machine.

Comment: I don't know about Twitter but in Facebook oauth you need to specify redirect uri, if it works for localhost you probably don't have your server ip configured

Comment: I ma looking at the apps dev settings on Twitter. The website and the call back is set to the domain name and domain.com/_oauth/twitter

Comment: accounts-facebook also doesnt work for me.

Comment: When i change to ipaddres and ipaddress/_oauth/twitter 

It still doesnt work.